# Increase UiTextView size as text increases

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want my UITextView size to be increased according to the text in it and if the text is long then it should allow scrolling. How can this be achieved? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will make my day, may also helps you

```
 func adjustTextView(_ textView : UITextView) {
        textView.scrollEnabled = false
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        textView.sizeToFit()
    }
```